# health_manager What is supposed to happen when a CRASHED droplet is reported on dea.heartbeat

Tags: cloud-foundry

I'm trying to understand exactly what happens when an instance of my app dies and at the moment I'm not seeing the behavior I expected.  In short, I am 
pushing a simple ruby app (not bound to any services).
scaling the app to 2 instances
using the warden repl to kill one of the warden containers
At this point I see the following message on NATS

```
Msg received on [dea.heartbeat] : '{"droplets":[
 {"cc_partition":"ng","droplet":"8799bc94-aec2-4d9b-89fe-afe0b19ee70e","version":"3ab998c8-30b0-4463-900c-5b24f5661d5e","instance":"648c67d73451faa56e3f06c116170ea5","index":0,"state":"CRASHED","state_timestamp":1371618457.4275367},
 {"cc_partition":"ng","droplet":"8799bc94-aec2-4d9b-89fe-afe0b19ee70e","version":"3ab998c8-30b0-4463-900c-5b24f5661d5e","instance":"912bae76e7bdb5e6a109f277c26d3329","index":1,"state":"RUNNING","state_timestamp":1371618268.9850419}],
"dea":"0-decc0f9337d3e9dd5d2f4fb5c720a9e2","prod":false}'
```

As you can see, one of the two instances has a state of CRASHED.  I can look in the health_manager log and see that the heartbeat message is getting processed, but a new app instance is never started.  I've done an initial read through the health manager code and haven't been able to find any evidence that a restart is tried.

What is supposed to happen as a result of the above message?

This is all on v2, btw.

(cross-posting on vcap-dev)